# where is ant installed on Mac OS X snow leopard by default?

Tags: macos, ant, osx-leopard

I don't have ANT_HOME set, so i want to find where the home directory of ant is. I'm using the version of ant that was installed by default on my OSX install.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

Follow these instructions to find the location of any package:

```
whereis ant (replace 'ant' with whatever you're looking for)
```

On my machine, this reports:

```
/usr/bin/ant
```

so, I do:

```
ls -l /usr/bin/ant
```

on my machine this reports:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  22 Nov 30 17:09 /usr/bin/ant -> /usr/share/ant/bin/ant
```

so, I do :

```
ls -l /usr/share/ant
```

and get:

```
lrwxr-xr-x  1 root  wheel  14 Nov 30 17:09 /usr/share/ant -> java/ant-1.8.1
```

from this I can surmise that ant is installed at  `/usr/share/ant/java/ant-1.8.1`

Comment: You can also do "which ant" instead of using "whereis..."

Comment: Correction: The path would be /usr/share/java/ant-1.8.1

Comment: This dies not help to find the location of ANT_HOME on every system. Using `ant -diagnostics | grep ant.home` is more precise.

Comment: I admit the question could be confusing. Not having ANT_HOME set as an exported environment variable on OSX seems to be totally common, at least on the 10 OSX servers I manage. Nevertheless ant -diagnostic tells you its default value of ant.home, even if the environment variable ANT_HOME is not set. If ant is not even on the PATH, which wouldn't allow for querying the diagnostics, and you're looking for the binary, you may even want to use `find / -name "ant" -type f`.

Answer (score 28):

If you run ant -diagnostics, it should tell you where the ant.home is

```
$ant -diagnostics 

-------------------------------------------
ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.2 compiled on July 8 2013
ant.java.version: 1.6
ant.core.lib: /opt/local/share/java/apache-ant/lib/ant.jar
ant.home: /opt/local/share/java/apache-ant
```

Comment: This produces an error: `Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher`

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky you probably need to add your JAVA_HOME in env variable

Answer (score 1):

I do not had `ANT` at all in whole system, but i use NetBeans 8.1 or 8.2.

**Step 1:** Install NetBeans 8.2

**Step 2:** Apply the ant from NetBeans 8.2 does the easy job too

```
$ "/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/bin/ant" -diagnostics
------- Ant diagnostics report -------
Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016

-------------------------------------------
 Implementation Version
-------------------------------------------
core tasks     : 1.9.7 in file:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans%208.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant.jar

-------------------------------------------
 ANT PROPERTIES
-------------------------------------------
ant.version: Apache Ant(TM) version 1.9.7 compiled on April 9 2016
ant.java.version: 1.8
Is this the Apache Harmony VM? no
Is this the Kaffe VM? no
Is this gij/gcj? no
ant.core.lib: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant.jar
ant.home: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant

-------------------------------------------
 ANT_HOME/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
ant.home: /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant
ant-antlr.jar (11563 bytes)
ant-apache-bcel.jar (15077 bytes)
ant-apache-bsf.jar (9827 bytes)
ant-apache-log4j.jar (8676 bytes)
ant-apache-oro.jar (9805 bytes)
ant-apache-regexp.jar (9671 bytes)
ant-apache-resolver.jar (9748 bytes)
ant-apache-xalan2.jar (8197 bytes)
ant-commons-logging.jar (9791 bytes)
ant-commons-net.jar (90789 bytes)
ant-jai.jar (28321 bytes)
ant-javamail.jar (13778 bytes)
ant-jdepend.jar (13826 bytes)
ant-jmf.jar (12386 bytes)
ant-jsch.jar (48991 bytes)
ant-junit.jar (117485 bytes)
ant-junit4.jar (13196 bytes)
ant-launcher.jar (18334 bytes)
ant-netrexx.jar (16279 bytes)
ant-swing.jar (13274 bytes)
ant-testutil.jar (27034 bytes)
ant.jar (2027962 bytes)

-------------------------------------------
 USER_HOME/.ant/lib jar listing
-------------------------------------------
user.home: /Users/sun
No such directory.

-------------------------------------------
 Tasks availability
-------------------------------------------
sshexec : Missing dependency com.jcraft.jsch.Logger
scp : Missing dependency com.jcraft.jsch.Logger
sshsession : Missing dependency com.jcraft.jsch.Logger
jdepend : Missing dependency jdepend.xmlui.JDepend
A task being missing/unavailable should only matter if you are trying to use it

-------------------------------------------
 org.apache.env.Which diagnostics
-------------------------------------------
Not available.
Download it at http://xml.apache.org/commons/

-------------------------------------------
 XML Parser information
-------------------------------------------
XML Parser : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl
XML Parser Location: unknown
Namespace-aware parser : com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.SAXParserImpl$JAXPSAXParser
Namespace-aware parser Location: unknown

-------------------------------------------
 XSLT Processor information
-------------------------------------------
XSLT Processor : com.sun.org.apache.xalan.internal.xsltc.trax.TransformerImpl
XSLT Processor Location: unknown

-------------------------------------------
 System properties
-------------------------------------------
java.runtime.name : Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment
sun.boot.library.path : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib
java.vm.version : 25.31-b07
ant.library.dir : /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib
user.country.format : BE
gopherProxySet : false
java.vm.vendor : Oracle Corporation
java.vendor.url : http://java.oracle.com/
path.separator : :
java.vm.name : Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM
file.encoding.pkg : sun.io
user.country : US
sun.java.launcher : SUN_STANDARD
sun.os.patch.level : unknown
java.vm.specification.name : Java Virtual Machine Specification
user.dir : /Users/sun/Desktop/android/android-webrtc-master
java.runtime.version : 1.8.0_31-b13
java.awt.graphicsenv : sun.awt.CGraphicsEnvironment
java.endorsed.dirs : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/endorsed
os.arch : x86_64
java.io.tmpdir : /var/folders/zq/zqbl2b1x43g6kq5bxmgx39880000gn/T/
line.separator : 

java.vm.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
os.name : Mac OS X
ant.home : /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant
sun.jnu.encoding : UTF-8
java.library.path : /Users/sun/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java:.
java.specification.name : Java Platform API Specification
java.class.version : 52.0
sun.management.compiler : HotSpot 64-Bit Tiered Compilers
os.version : 10.11.6
http.nonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
user.home : /Users/sun
user.timezone : Europe/Brussels
java.awt.printerjob : sun.lwawt.macosx.CPrinterJob
java.specification.version : 1.8
file.encoding : UTF-8
user.name : sun
java.class.path : /Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-antlr.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-bcel.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-bsf.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-log4j.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-oro.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-regexp.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-resolver.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-apache-xalan2.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-commons-logging.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-commons-net.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-jai.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-javamail.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-jdepend.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-jmf.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-jsch.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-junit.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-junit4.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-launcher.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-netrexx.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-swing.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant-testutil.jar:/Applications/NetBeans/NetBeans 8.2.app/Contents/Resources/NetBeans/extide/ant/lib/ant.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/lib/tools.jar
java.vm.specification.version : 1.8
sun.arch.data.model : 64
java.home : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre
sun.java.command : org.apache.tools.ant.launch.Launcher -cp  -diagnostics
java.specification.vendor : Oracle Corporation
user.language : en
awt.toolkit : sun.lwawt.macosx.LWCToolkit
java.vm.info : mixed mode
java.version : 1.8.0_31
java.ext.dirs : /Users/sun/Library/Java/Extensions:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/ext:/Library/Java/Extensions:/Network/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java
sun.boot.class.path : /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/resources.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/rt.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/sunrsasign.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jsse.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jce.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/charsets.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/jfr.jar:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_31.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/classes
java.vendor : Oracle Corporation
file.separator : /
java.vendor.url.bug : http://bugreport.sun.com/bugreport/
sun.cpu.endian : little
sun.io.unicode.encoding : UnicodeBig
socksNonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
ftp.nonProxyHosts : local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16
sun.cpu.isalist : 

-------------------------------------------
 Temp dir
-------------------------------------------
Temp dir is /var/folders/zq/zqbl2b1x43g6kq5bxmgx39880000gn/T/
Temp dir is writeable
Temp dir alignment with system clock is -6 ms

-------------------------------------------
 Locale information
-------------------------------------------
Timezone Central European Time offset=3600000

-------------------------------------------
 Proxy information
-------------------------------------------
http.nonProxyHosts = "local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16"
ftp.nonProxyHosts = "local|*.local|169.254/16|*.169.254/16"
Java1.5+ proxy settings:
Direct connection
```

Answer (score 0):

try looking in /usr/bin folder .. it should tell you where it is installed.