# Cannot select key on Macintosh with Filezilla

Tags: macos, ssh-keys, filezilla

I am trying to use FileZilla -> Preferences -> Connection -> SFTP to import my ssh key, but that key is in the hidden ~/.ssh directory. The file selection box does not see it. Any suggestions?

Comment: From the FAQ: practical, answerable problems that are unique to the programming profession - as far as I know, being able to upload your code to a server is a problem unique to the programming profession, and if it's offtopic, how could filezilla, ssh-keys and osx all be predefined tags?

Comment: @OP - but they're supposed to be programming (language) questions, not how to manipulate programs to do what I want to do

Comment: You mean stuff like this:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4823367/where-is-ant-installed-on-mac-os-x-snow-leopard-by-default/4823404#4823404 is not allowed?